# SQLAlchemy Reflection Failing in Python 3.6 with PyMySQL

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-3.6

Howdie do,

I'm attempting to use Python 3.6 with SQLAlchemy. I am able to connect to the database, but all reflection attempts are failing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jw1050/Python/projects/label_automation/generate.py", line 14, in <module>
    metadata.reflect(engine, only=['parcel', 'order', 'address', 'document'])
  File "/Users/jw1050/.virtualenvs/psd_label_automatiion/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3874, in reflect
    bind.engine.table_names(schema, connection=conn))
  File "/Users/jw1050/.virtualenvs/psd_label_automatiion/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2128, in table_names
    return self.dialect.get_table_names(conn, schema)
  File "<string>", line 2, in get_table_names
  File "/Users/jw1050/.virtualenvs/psd_label_automatiion/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 42, in cache
    return fn(self, con, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/jw1050/.virtualenvs/psd_label_automatiion/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 1756, in get_table_names
    self.identifier_preparer.quote_identifier(current_schema))
  File "/Users/jw1050/.virtualenvs/psd_label_automatiion/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2888, in quote_identifier
    self._escape_identifier(value) + \
  File "/Users/jw1050/.virtualenvs/psd_label_automatiion/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 78, in _escape_identifier
    value = value.replace(self.escape_quote, self.escape_to_quote)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

My connection information is below:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://:127.0.0.1:3306/(db_name)?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0')
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))()

metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine, only=['parcel', 'order', 'address', 'document'])
Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
Base.prepare()
```

Everything works fine in Python 2, but I do not want to use Python 2 here. Has anybody else run into this issue and able to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out.

This was due to my connection string having use_unicode=0 in it.

According to the [SQLAlchemy Docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#unicode-encoding-decoding) this setting should never be used in Python3. In Python 2, it gives superior performance but not in Python 3

Hopefully this helps someone